# What method is called immediately when view is shown on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, state, navigator

I've a screen to show data loaded from files to the user, and these data are updated periodically from a remote service. To read files and show to user, I'm calling a load data method from `void initState()`, but on this way, that method is called just one time when the screen has created, so when any change happens the screen is not updated. Another option is call load data method from `Widget build(BuildContext context)`, but that called a lot of times, and I don't want it. I want wrote some thing like used on Swift `viewWillAppear()` but I don't found a method to do it.

I must load data every time that user navigate to the screen, from any local, I'm using `Navigator.push()` and `Navigator.pop()` to navigate between screens.

**Screen: HomePage**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {    
    print('HOME SCREEN INIT STATE');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
      return new Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddExpensePage()));
            },
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7B7BAD),
        ),
      ...
     }
```

**Screen: AddExpensePage**

```
class AddExpensePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new AddExpensePageState();
}

class AddExpensePageState extends State<AddExpensePage> {

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Scenario: The main screen is `HomePage`, at first time, `initState()` is called, so I navigate to `AddExpensePage`, and from `AddExpensePage` I click on back arrow to return to `HomePage`, when returns, none method is called to listen when screen is showed.

Comment: That's `initState`. I understand how it doesn't fit your use-case. Can you clarify that part?

Comment: The `initState` method is called just one time of all life of app. Independent if I navigate and pop screens.

Comment: It is not. `initState` can be called again under many circumstances, such as key change.

Comment: No, `initState` isn't called when I back to the main screen. If I navigate from A to B, and from B return to A, `initState` of A ins't called.

Comment: You probably want to use `RouteAware` then. Or the future returned by `pop`\

Answer (score -1):

There isn't something like `viewWillAppear`, but the right hooks for that in flutter are [`initState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) and [`didUpdateWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html). And then make sure to clean up on `dispose`.

- `initState` is called the first time your state is attached to the tree
- `didUpdateWidget` is called every time that same state is attached to a new widget afterwards.